# Woocommerce - adding possibility to add note to order via customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there way to allow customer to add note to order (after purchase) on his order page (my-account/show-order/{order_no}/)
Or maybe is there any plugin for it?

For example: client purchased some items and he forgot to note something to this order. I would like to give him posibility to add note directly to this order.

Comment: this can certainly help you on your way https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-edit-orders/

Comment: well, there is almost everything what I need but I can't let a customer edit whole order when it's in processing.

Comment: Well, then you have to adjust the code to your needs, if you have additional questions, you can always ask for help here. Regards